# How to translate single page in django?

Tags: django, translation

I have only one page i want to translate and im using downloaded [application](http://django-envelope.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) (with locale folder in it).

I want to get output from this app with translated values on one single page.

How can i tell the the template or view to show translated values?

Comment: Have you set [language-code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#language-code) correctly? What do you mean by _single_? Do you want that one page in a different language from the other pages of your website? Or do you want that page to be shown in the language of the browser of the user?

Comment: i want to set language on one page only. I dont care about users browser settings

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want the page to be in a different language than what you have set for your website.

Here is two lines of the code of the middleware which manages languages in [our dual-language website](http://cafebazaar.ir/?l=en) but I guess in your case, it can be placed at the beginning of your view function:

```
django.utils.translation.activate(desired_lang)
request.LANGUAGE_CODE = django.utils.translation.get_language()
```